# Linux Kernel support for ARM Cortex-A78

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, emulator

I am planning to boot Linux for an ARM Cortex A78 based system.
And I have some doubts about the same.

**1. Which kernel version should I select ?**
I checked 5.4.112, 5.10.30, 5.11.14, 5.12-rc7 kernels, for ARM_CPU_PART_CORTEX_A78 into root/arch/arm64/include/cputype.h, but no match.
Can you suggest a Kernel version which has Cortex-A78 support? OR
Can you suggest any patch that can add support of Cortex-A78 to a kernel?

**2. My target platform/machine is an Emulator, with an ARM Cortex A78 core and a DDR RAM only. No other peripherals for now.**
What should be the minimal kernel configurations for this machine?
Which options in defconfig can be selected as ‘no’, while configuring the kernel, with guarantee that the selected minimal configurations will surely boot up Linux in the above mentioned platform?

**3. Should I use an uncompressed image or compressed one?**
Please note, I am planning to place the compiled Linux image’s binary into the RAM, at a location where the A78 will jump upon reset. If required, we’ll also develop basic boot code for A78, which will allow the processor to jump to Linux Image location in the RAM.

I know that booting Linux on embedded devices requires more software components, like bood code, FSBL, uboot, etc.
But, I just want to experiment and that's why I want to compile the smallest possible Linux for ARM Cortex-A78 and A DDR RAM system, and want to see the same system running with Linux.

Apart from the answers of above questions, your suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Please feel free to inform me, if I am unclear to you at any point.

Thanks & Regards,
Maunik Patel

Comment: Could you add something about what you're planning to *do* with the system? Just CPU and DRAM doesn't let you do more than running code through an external debugger.

Comment: You are perfectly right. I can't do much with this setup. Other peripherals will be added later, for sure. But before that, I just want to check if this minimal system can run the smallest possible Linux or not, and want to face the challenges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Linux version

You don't need any specific Linux kernel versions. Modern ARM CPUs report their supported features via ID registers - the kernel does not need specific knowledge of the exact processor you're using. Go for the most recent kernel you can.

2. Minimum platform

The only real requirement for running Linux is an interrupt controller - and the Cortex-A78 is designed to work with one conformant to ARM's GICv4 specification - and a timer (included in the A78). But you will want some way to interact with the system - and a serial console on UART is the way to do that.

If you bypass EL3 completely, and write a wrapper that drops into EL2 and runs the kernel there, you may have no need for a separate console for Secure world. Then again, UARTs are cheap, so maybe add a spare one anyway.
However, as soon as you're looking at running more than one core, you need a PSCI implementation. At that point, you might as well bring in Trusted Firmware-A as your EL3 firmware.

Then you need a device tree describing the DRAM, CPU(s), UART, GIC, and generic timers. (And any PSCI hooks.)

3. Compressed kernel or not

64-bit ARM does not support a standalone executable self-decompressing zImage like 32-bit ARM. There is no value in compressing the kernel unless you start worrying about storage space.

Comment: Thank you @unixsmurf, for the answer. I am sure that, this information is going to be a big help to me.